# Can CSS ::before pseudo property constrain to a width assignment when using a font?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am utilizing FontAwesome fonts to push icons in my current project and was wanting to utilize the ::before pseudo property on some labels.

As you see in the image below the alignment of the labels is off. I was hoping to resolve this using the 'width' property to ensure the icons take up the same amount of space horizontally.

[image: Images not aligned]

The CSS I am currently using is

```
.title::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width:35px; // this can be 34523px and still does nothing for the view
 }

&.error .title::before {
    content: $fa-var-exclamation-circle;
    color: $color_error;
}
```

AlthoughI know the object is a font glyph and has it's own font-size. I do not want to manipulate the font-size of the wider icon to accommodate the difference. When I apply the width as is, there is no change, as I stated above.

It seems like this is a rational element to style. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you try add `display: inline-block;` combined with the width?

Comment: I did now...bingo...where can I ship the beer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make it answer then: Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the element --> http://jsfiddle.net/d72bo9q1/1/

```css
.xxx:before {
    content: 'x';
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.xxx {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="xxx">bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: the margin-right is always relative to the content in the ::before so I would take that out...the display: inline-block was all it needed to behave as expected

Comment: @beauXjames what about no beer but you mark my answer as the correct one? it's a bad deal for me but anyhow then its all done and we're even :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center;` to `.title::before`

```
.title::before {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width:35px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The `display: inline-block;` allows you to set an width to the element. `text-align: center;` makes sure the icons are centered over each others.

Hope it helps.